# Ocaml implementation

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I got a slight problem implementing arrays in ocaml. For example, when on the terminal(konsole) and I type

```
let tab = Array.make 5 6;
```

I have

```
val tab : int array = [|6; 6; 6; 6; 6|]
```

as an output. So it creates an array with a length of 5 and fills all the cases with 6. Okay I understand that part. But when I type it on a text editor like kate for example, save it and compile it it I get this error:

```
Error: Unbound value Array.make
```

I don't understand why it takes Array. make as a value in kate and it takes Array.make as a function in the terminal. I saved the file with the ".ml" extension and I compile it using `ocamlc -o test name_of_file`. 
Any suggestions please? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I compiled your program with `ocamlc` and it went fine (using OCaml 3.12.0).

I would guess that you are calling an old version of the compiler when you try to compile, perhaps one from when `Array.make` was still named `Array.create`. Perhaps when you installed the new version, you overwrote some of the files (such as the toplevel) but not others (such as the compiler). In order to check, compare the versions given by `ocamlc -v` and `ocaml`.

As for the message “Unbound value”, in OCaml, functions are values. The implementors did not differentiate between “Unbound value that is not a function” and “Unbound value that is a function”, but this is not the cause of the problem. The cause of your problem is that `Array.make` is unbound at all.

Comment: Both of them gave me the same version. Version 3.11.2. I don't think I overwrote any files belonging to a previous version. I just installed linux on my pc, so I didn't have ant previous version of ocaml. I verified by just typing ocaml and it wrote that ocaml isn't installed yet so I just installed it.. this version 3.11.2. I tried Array.create but i still get the same problem. Do you think it's because of the version i'm using?

Comment: @mktab It definitely should work with version 3.11.2. Version 3.12.0 would tell you if it's module `Array` or function `make` therein that is unbound, one of many small improvements that this version brought, but the error you are getting remains a mystery.

Comment: @mktab It is likely that the file .../lib/ocaml/array.cmi is not found by the compiler. Perhaps it is missing, or your distribution's package was improperly prepared by copying files in a destination other than the compiler was configured to be installed in. If it is the case, you could fix it by using options -I and -L, but I'd recommend re-compiling OCaml from sources.

Comment: That would be strange if it were missing; wouldn't that mean the top-level invocation wouldn't work either? I do suspect something is seriously wrong with the environment variables or the installation, though.

Answer (score 3):

I found the error. It's a very stupid one. I saved my file as "array.ml". So during the compilation it created an array.cmi file and I think it kinda confused this file with the one found in .../lib/ocaml/array.cmi. I'm not really sure. So I renamed the file to "table.ml" and it compiled perfectly. It's crazy that it confused these two files

Comment: How to explicitly specify `../lib/ocaml/array.cmi` then?